# Make reftex-mode work with a different citation format

Tags: latex, markdown, reftex-mode

By default reftex-mode recognizes LaTeX-like citations, which have a format like `\cite{Smith15}`.  (Locating the cursor above a reference shows a description of it in the mini-buffer and pressing `C-&` opens the bibliography file in the right spot).

I would like reftex-mode to also recognize my Pandoc-like citations, which have a format like `@Smith15` (regexp:`"@[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+"`).

Reftex-mode has some functions that allow extending it (e.g., `reftex-cite-format`, `reftex-view-crossref-extra`), but it is not clear how to use them to detect this type of citation.

Any ideas?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607156/autocomplete-pandoc-style-citations-from-a-bibtex-file-in-emacs) is related: it discusses how to use RefTeX to _insert_ Pandoc citations, but not how to make it _recognize_ Pandoc citations.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the format of citations is hard-coded as the latex one in reftex source code (see function `reftex-view-crossref` in file `reftex-dcr.el`), so there's no easy way to change it.  However, if what you need is just to be able to look up the citation at point, the following does it:

```el
(require 'reftex-dcr)
(defun my-reftex-view-pandoc-cite ()
   "View pandoc citation"
   (interactive)
   (let ((w (word-at-point)))
    (if (eq ?@ (elt w 0))
    (setq dw (reftex-view-cr-cite "" (substring w 1) 'tmp-window))
      (if (and (eq arg 2) (windowp dw)) (select-window dw))
      (error "Not on a citation")
      )))
```

You don't need to enable `reftex-mode` but you have to tell RefTex about your bibliography file:

```el
(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("biblio"))
```

Something similar could be done for the 'idle display' feature, but it may be more complex.